# Set option list to read only in java using formHTML.append

Tags: javascript, html, forms

So i have a dropdownlist that i am appending on to the html form using formHTML.append

the issue is i need to make certain dropdownlist `readonly` since im setting the value from somewhere else and i dont want the user to be able to change the value while submitting the form.

this is what i am currently doing to display the dropdown list, how do i add readonly attribute to this ?

i need to be able to make `checkboxlist` and `radiobutton` list and rating control also read only is it possible ?

```
formHTML.append("<option value=\"" + selectOpt.getOptionValue() + "\"" + selDefault  +">" + selectOpt.getOptionText() + "</option>");
```

Comment: Java has nothing to do with JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`readonly` is not a valid property for `option` nor for `select` tags you should use `disabled` property.

I guess that the `formHTML` contain `select` tag so you could set the `disabled` to it using :

```
formHTML.setAttribute('disabled', true);
```

If you want to send value on submit you could use `hidden` field :

```
<input type="hidden" name="select_name" value="selected value" />
```

Or you could add event listner on submit then remove `disabled` attribute :

```
var form = document.forms[0]; 

form.addEventListener("submit", function(evt){
    document.getElementById('select-id').disabled = false;
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but if i set the attribute as disabled, i wont get the value of the field while submitting.

Comment: Thanks, will this method also work for checkbox list. radio button list and rating control?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want `readonly` on the `option` you want `disabled` on the `select`.

Something like:

```
<select ... disabled></select>
```